# Big-$O$ verification [discrete mathematics]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, recreational-mathematics

I've come across challenge proof question in my discrete mathematics textbook that I'm trying to solve for practice but unfortunately it does not have a solution. Any help with a reasonable explanation or solution so that I can understand where to start and verify my work would be greatly appreciated:

> Suppose that $f$, $g$ and $h$ are all functions from $\mathbf{N}$ into
>   $\mathbf{R^+}$. Prove that if $f + g \notin O(h)$, then either $f
> > \notin O(h)$, or $g \notin O(h)$ (or both).
>
> Recall that $f \in O(h)$ if and only if $\exists c \in \mathbf{R}^+,
> > \exists n_0 \in \mathbf{N}, \forall n \in \mathbf{N}, n \ge n_0
> > \implies f(n) \le ch(n)$. We define $f + g$ to be the function such
>   that $(f + g)(n) = f(n) + g(n)$ for every element $n$ of $\mathbf{N}$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$f+g \not\in O(h)$
means that,
for any $c > 0$,
there is a value of $x$
such that
$f(x)+g(x) > ch(x)$.

$f \in O(h)$
means that,
for all large enough $x$,
there is a $c > 0$
such that
$f(x) < ch(x)$
and similarly for $g$.

If both
$f \in O(h)$ and
$g \in O(h)$
there are
$c_f$ and $c_g$
such that,
for all large enough $x$,
$f(x) < c_fh(x)$
and
$g(x) < c_gh(x)$.

Therefore,
for all large enough $x$,
$f(x)+g(x)
\lt (c_f+c_g)h(x)$,
so that
$f+g \in O(h)$.